# Infoblox perl api error 1002- arguments missing or incorrect when creating DNS zones

Tags: perl, infoblox

I am setting up a perl script for communicating with some infoblox appliances running NIOS 5.1, and I am stuck at the below portion of the code. This part is used to create Reverse Zone records.

Any pointers what I might be doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require Infoblox;
use Getopt::Std;
use Term::GetKey;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use VCIM qw ( load_config getline unpack_netmask pack_netmask validate_netmask validate_vlan        get_first_ip get_last_ip get_next_ip dprint
write_config i18n hash_merge dqtobin bintodq binmax binmin ip_is_used );

my $DEBUG=1;
my $overwrite=0;

my $match;

my %options;
getopts('yp:', \%options);

if (defined $options{'y'}) {
$overwrite = 1;
}

# read settings from settings.conf
my %config;
%config = %{load_config()};

# acquire infoblox handle
dprint("\nConnecting to $infobloxip as $infobloxuser" . ($infobloxpass eq 'default' ? " using     default password 'default'":"")."\n");
my $ibh = Infoblox::Session->new(
master => $infobloxip,
password => $infobloxpass,
username => $infobloxuser
);
my @searchres = $ibh->search(
"object" => "Infoblox::Grid::Member",
"name" => ".*"
);
unless (@searchres) {
if ( defined $config{'credentials'}{'infobloxPass'} ) {
dprint("Connection failed. (Status Code " . $ibh->status_code() . ": " . $ibh->status_detail() . ").\n");
dprint("Trying again. Will use config password instead.\n");
$infobloxpass = $config{'credentials'}{'infobloxPass'};
$ibh = Infoblox::Session->new(
  master => $infobloxip,
  password => $infobloxpass,
  username => $infobloxuser);
@searchres = $ibh->search(
  "object" => "Infoblox::Grid::Member",
  "name" => ".*"
);
unless (@searchres) {
  die ($ibh->status_code() . ':' . $ibh->status_detail());
}
} else {
die ($ibh->status_code() . ':' . $ibh->status_detail());
}
}

sub create_zones {
my $oct0 = shift;
my $oct1 = shift;
my $oct2 = shift;
my $netbits = shift;
$netbits = ($netbits>24?24:$netbits);
#one network for /8, /16, /24, or  2^x where x is each bit less than the classful boundary
$networks = ($netbits%8==0?1:(2**(8-($netbits%8))));
my $snb = ($netbits<24 && $netbits>16 ? \$oct2 : ($netbits > 8 ? \$oct1 : \$oct0));
for (my $i=0;$i<$networks;$i++) {
if ($i>0) {
${$snb}++;
}
dprint("Creating Reverse zone $oct2.$oct1.$oct0.in-addr.arpa... ");
my $newzone = Infoblox::DNS::Zone->new(
name  => $oct2.".".$oct1.".".$oct0."."."0"."/".($netbits%8==0?$netbits:$netbits + (8 - ($netbits%8))),
enable_rfc2317_exclusion => "true",
disable => "false",
primary => $dns_member
);
unless (my $response = $ibh->add($newzone)) {
  unless ($ibh->status_code() == 1005) {
    die ($ibh->status_code() . ":" . $ibh->status_detail());
  }
```

The complete error code is `1002:One or more arguments in request are missing or incorrect at infobloxSetup.pl line 601, <RUC> line 657.`

Comment: `$oct2.".".$oct1.".".$oct0."."."0"."/"` is better written `"$oct2.$oct1.$oct0.0/"`. You should probably put more into your question than code, though. That's like taking your car to the garage and saying "Fix it." Include all error messages, your expected output, actual output, some test data, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out it wasn't perl related, the problem was that       enable_rfc2317_exclusion => "true" was not supported in the API version I am using, it was written for newer Infoblox versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't perl related, the problem was that enable_rfc2317_exclusion => "true" was not supported in the API version I was using